# In Google sheets, can the REGEXEXTRACT formula pull from a list of words located on a separate tab?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here's my formula (that currently works):

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"wheel|tire|light|oil|battery")," ")
```

However, because my list of keywords is going to 1) get MUCH larger (as many as 200 items) and 2) because the list will be somewhat dynamic (some keywords may get removed down the road), I thought it might be easier to maintain the list separately (rather than do it inside the formula).

I think a TEXTJOIN formula can possibly be nested inside the REGEXEXTRACT formula(???), but I'm not sure as an exhaustive search on the internet has proven to be of little help.

Answer (score 0):

yes your idea is right about using `textjoin()`; lets say you accommodate the words list in `Column F` the formula would be in the lines of:

```
=ifna(regexextract(D2,textjoin("|",1,F:F)))
```

Comment: Awesome! And if it's a separate tab, I believe it'll look something like this:
=ifna(regexextract(D2,textjoin("|",1,MyList!F:F)))

Comment: yes... that's right